# How do you change fancy page numbering style after specific point in report?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I'm writing a report in which I want to have separate numbering styles before and after the introduction. For the executive summary and toc I want to have no page numbering, and following this (up to the introduction) I want to have lowercase roman numeral numbering in the bottom right corner, for example just 'iv'. For the introduction onwards I want arabic numbering in the style 'Page X of X' in the bottom right corner.

[image]

I've got the correct styling for the latter sections, however the method I've used to do this also applies this style to the front matter (e.g. 'Page ii of 2').

[image]

I'm unsure how to redefine the `\rfoot` style after a particular section or how to overwrite the numbering format on particular pages, but retain the fancy page styling.

Below is a MWE of my report.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[top=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{fancy}
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Executive Summary}
\thispagestyle{empty}

Some text

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter*{Glossary}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter*{List of abbreviations}

\listoffigures

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

Some text

\chapter{First Chapter}

Some text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to define different page styles for the different parts. For the Executive summary you can use `\pagestyle{empty}` as you apparently don't want any headers or footers there. For the two other parts I defined two page styles `frontmatter` and `mainmatter`, that contains the footer definitions. I also put the `\pagenumbering` command there to keep everything together.

Please note that usually it is important to give a `\newpage`, `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` (whatever is appropriate) before the `\pagestyle` command, otherwise the previous page might be affected.

If you want to add headers, it is best to do that inside the `\fancypagestyle` commands too.

And, by the way, I generally advise against the use of the old-fashioned commands like `\rfoot`. It is usually better to use `\fancyfoot` etc, especially if you want to differentiate between even and odd pages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[top=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancypagestyle{frontmatter}{
  \pagenumbering{roman}
  \rfoot{\thepage}
}
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{fancy}
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\chapter*{Executive Summary}
\thispagestyle{empty}

Some text

\clearpage
\pagestyle{frontmatter}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter*{Glossary}

\chapter*{List of abbreviations}

\listoffigures

\clearpage
\pagestyle{mainmatter}
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}


Some text

\chapter{First Chapter}

Some text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply three  different styles: `empty` (already defined), to `frontmatter` (roman numbering) and to `mainmatter` (Page X of X). The last two have to be defined.

When you apply `\pagestyle{<style>}`, it will be effective from that place forward (after a clearpage).

The redefinition of the chapter command takes care of the necessary clearpage for `\chapter` and `\chapter*`; and also of the style of the first page of a chapter. Otherwise it will be in style `plain` (arabic page number in the center of the footer)

I added `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` to suppress the header rule. If you want to add a footer rule add `\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}` in the preamble.

Glossary will have the number `i` in the footer while Introduction will have `Page 1 of 2`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[top=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}   

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{%
    \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi% a
%   \thispagestyle{fancy} % not needed <<<<<
    \global\@topnum\z@%
    \@afterindentfalse%
    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother

\fancypagestyle{frontmatter}{% 
    \fancyhf{}% clear previous definitions
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
}

\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
    \fancyhf{}% clear previous definitions
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% no upper rule <<<<<
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}% optional foot rule <<<<<

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty} % starts style empty <<<<<<<<<<
    
    \chapter*{Executive Summary}
        
    Some text
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter*{Glossary}
    \pagestyle{frontmatter} % starts style frontmatter <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
    \chapter*{List of abbreviations}
    
    \listoffigures

    \chapter*{Introduction} 
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
    \pagestyle{mainmatter} % starts style mainmatter <<<<<<<<<<<
    
    Some text
    
    \chapter{First Chapter}
    Some text   
        
\end{document}
```